# How to use LIKE operator to only include fields with certain special character?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do is I want to filter from a table where it specifically starts with something but when I try to filter out 'BRA_' it should only give me fields that has BRA_ on it and not BRAzil BRAma which is what the Like % operator is giving me. I also tried using Like _ but that only took the underscore out completely. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your query - I can't make sense of your dscription.

Comment: Try `WHERE Name LIKE 'BRA[_]%'`. The `_` is a single character wildcard in `LIKE` patterns, but it loses its special meaning when contained in a `[...]` character set/range.`WHERE LEFT(Name, 4) = 'BRA_'` might also work, but it risks triggering an error if names shorter than 4 characters are encountered.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  MyColumn Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE 'BRA?_' ESCAPE '?'
```

In the LIKE operator, ESCAPE create your own escape char that must be placed before the joker character that you would find as a litteral in the string.